# Two threads using same function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Basic using threads question here.

I'm modifying a program with 2 thread classes and I'd like to use a function defined in one class in both classes now.

As a thread newbie (only been playing with them for a few months) is it OK to move the function out of the thread class into the main program and just call it from both classes or do I need to duplicate the function in the other class that doesn't have it?

regards
Simon

Comment: can you give a flavour of what this function does? As long as it's not referencing global state you should fine unless using ``Queue`` etc. If it's a function that performs a calculation then where do you expect to stick the result ? Who wants to see the result? etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the same function from both threads.  The issue to be aware of is modifying shared data from two threads at once.  If the function attempts to modify the same data from both threads, you will end up with an unpredictable program.

So the answer to your question is, "it depends what the function does."

It certainly won't help to copy the function into both thread classes.  What matters is what the function does, not how many copies of the code there are.

Comment: So no issue with something that say simply returns the square of its arguments

Comment: No, but if your functions are compute-bound, then multiple threads will probably run more slowly than one thread.

Answer (score 2):

might wanna checkout thread locking.  threads operating on 1 function/method can 'lock' that function in many languages so other threads can't access it at the same time.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)